# If a cell contains an item from a list then print value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been searching for this answer and can't seem to find it.

If a cell contains an item from a list then print value.

**A1 =** POS Debit - Visa Check Card 5909 - DOLLAR TR 2422 WESLEY PARK

**B1:B4 LIST =**
azmn
store
Dollar TR
Target

I've tried vlookups, ifs, and searches. I need help!

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us, basically List Items & their values,,, if Item list are in B1:B4 & their values in C1:C4 then any lookup formula either VLOOKUP or INDEX & MATCH will pull the value for Item in cell A1 in a adjacent cell!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the easiest solution here is to not have a list of keywords but rather a column for each keyword. Say you have columns headings "Transaction azmn store Dollar TR Target" in row 1. Then put in B2

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1, $A1)) and copy across to C2 to F2.

Search will find the first occurance of your keyword in the heading (case insensitive) and returns the character position where it occurs or the #VALUE! error value if it doesn't occur. Using the ISNUMBER function simplifies the answer to only "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Now if you want to be fancy slap an if statement in there to return the keyword itself

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1, $A1)),B$1,"")

Then hide all the keyword columns and put =B2&C2&D2&E2&F2 in G2

The benefits of this approach is you could pick up transactions with multiple keywords that might need manual adjustment. You could also add a new row above the header for eg. categories "Groceries Luxury Travel" and have the IF statement return the Category name instead of the keyword itself.